# How to multiply variables inplace in a dataframe of a long format?

Tags: r

In a dataframe with a long format such as `diamonds`:

```
 carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
  <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
```

How can I, for example, multiply every values in the `price` column by a constant where every row in the `clarity` column satisfies the condition `clarity='SI2'` ?

I know how to use `filter` to filter the dataframe and do whatever operation I like:

```
df1 <- diamonds
filter(df['price'], df['clarity']=='VS1')*1000

# output:
price
<dbl>
327000              
338000              
340000              
353000              
355000              
357000              
402000              
402000              
402000              
402000
```

But how do I replace the old values with a recalculated values in one go?

I was *sure* this would work just fine:

```
df['price'][df$clarity == 'VS1'] <- filter(df['price'], df['clarity']=='VS1')*1000
```

But I'm getting the error: `Error: Must assign to columns with a valid subscript vector`

It's been a while since I've dabbled with `R`, so I'm afraid I might be missing something very obvious.
Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want in-place modification, `data.table` might be what you are looking for:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[clarity == 'VS1', price := price*1000]
```

You hence modified values in place

Comment: I just realized I only missed a comma... But I'm really glad I did because your suggestion is *fantastic* Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index where you want to replace the values and multiply only those values by 1000. This can be done in base R by :

```
inds <- df$clarity == 'VS1'
df$price[inds] <- df$price[inds] * 1000
```

Or in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[clarity == 'VS1', price := price * 100]
```

---

A slightly inefficient solution would be `ifelse`/`if_else`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(price = if_else(clarity == 'VS1', price * 1000, price))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(price = case_when(clarity == 'VS1' ~ price * 1000, TRUE ~ price))
```